# How to compare two string and ignoring special character in c#

Tags: c#, string

I want to compare two strings in c# if one is having any special character then it should be ignored.Like if-

```
string a1= "he is a good guy";
string a2="h2$#%# is a good guy";
```

then after `string.ReferenceEquals(a1,a2)` it should return True?

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you read anything about [`ReferenceEquals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.object.referenceequals%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? Sorry, but your question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Try removing special charactes first and then compare ?

Comment: What is your definition of a special char? 2$#%# are just some chars, not special to me. Are you having a problem with the encoding of the string?

Comment: Ya, I read about ReferenceEquals it is used in string comparision.

Comment: No it's not. Read again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, [`ReferenceEquals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.object.referenceequals%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is not good here as it compares references, not values. Hence your code will be always false if you compare two different variables (and string won't be interned but it is a different story).

To compare string, use [`string.Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.string.equals%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. But at first, you must get rid of the special characters, it will be possible with help of Regex:

```
string a2 = "h2$#%# is a good guy";
string a3 = Regex.Replace(a1, @"[^\w\d\s]", "");
```

This tells that you want to replace everything that is not (`^`) a word character (`\w`), a digit (`\d`) or whitespace (`\s`) with an empty string.

Using it, your solution should look like:

```
string.Equals(Regex.Replace(a1, @"[^\w\d\s]", ""), 
              Regex.Replace(a2, @"[^\w\d\s]", ""));
```

To not repeat Regex code, you can write a helper extension method for string:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string RemoveSpecialCharacters(this string str)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(str, @"[^\w\d\s]", "");
    }
}
```

and your code will be:

```
string.Equals(a1.RemoveSpecialCharacters(), 
              a2.RemoveSpecialCharacters());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem by using Regular Expressions. Some great ressources about this topic can be found on:

1. The official msdn pages - http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx
2. Dotnetperls - http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-match
3. General, language independant regex in theorie - http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html

Edit:

I don't think, that ReferenceEquals is the thing you're looking for as the official [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.object.referenceequals%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) states:

> Determines whether the specified Object instances are the same instance.

You want to compare the content of the string so take a look at regex.

Answer (score 0):

You may define a custom comparison method.

Eg.

```
private string[] patternsToIgnore = new []{"#","$","%","2$"}; //expand it as you like;

public static CustomCompare(this string s, string otherString){
   var v1 = s;
   var v2 = otherString;
   foreach (var p in patternsToIgnore){
      v1 = v1.Replace(p, String.Empty);
      v2 = v2.Replace(p, String.Empty);
   }
   return v1 == v2;
}
```

Use it in the following way:

```
string a1= "he is a good guy";
string a2= "h2$#%#w is a good guy";

if (a1.CustomCompare(a2)){
  //you should now get here
}
```